# Understanding Pattern Matching with Sub-classes

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Lift has the [Box](http://liftweb.net/api/26/api/index.html#net.liftweb.common.Box) case class.

I wrote the following method to pattern match on a `Box[A]`:

```
scala> import net.liftweb.common._
import net.liftweb.common._

scala> def foo[A](box: Box[A]) = box match { 
     |   case Empty | Failure(_, _, _) => true
     |   case Full(_)                  => false
     | }
foo: [A](box: net.liftweb.common.Box[A])Boolean
```

I wrote this method to learn if `ParamFailure`, which is a sub-class of `Failure`, would pattern match on the `Failure(_, _, _)` case.

```
scala> val pf: Box[String] = ParamFailure("a", Empty, Empty, "blah")
pf: net.liftweb.common.Box[String] = ParamFailure(a, Empty, Empty, blah)
```

And, it did.

```
scala> foo(pf)
res9: Boolean = true
```

It's not clear to me why `ParamFailure` would match to `Failure(_, _, _)`. Why is that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the whole point of inheritance.  If `S` is a subclass of `C`, then you should be able to use `S` *absolutely everywhere* that you use `C` (this is called the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)).

Pattern matching is included.

Now, if you specifically want to tell if you have an `S` as opposed to a `C`, you can check for it:

```
class C {}
class S extends C {}
val c: C = new S
c match {
  case s: S => println("Actually, I was an S")
  case _ => println("Guess I was some other kind of C")
}
```

But if you ask if it's a `C`, the answer is yes:

```
c match {
  case c2: C => println("Yes, of course I am a C!")
  case _ => println("This would be super-weird.")
}
```

Again, adding pattern matching changes nothing here; whether you know the type and then pull out the parameters by hand, or whether Scala helpfully gives you identifiers for them, it works the same way.

```
case class P(p: Boolean) {}
object T extends P(true) {}
val p: P = T
p match {
  case P(tf) => println(tf)
  case _ => println("You will never reach here.")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is just how case classes are defined [in the spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#case-classes).

The extractor takes an instance of the case class (that is, the unapply method takes a C) and returns the elements of the first parameter list.

You could imagine other definitions, such as requiring that the erased type is exactly the same, or at least that `productArity` is the same.

Pattern matching is defined as [testing for a shape](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html), and not only or primarily as a type test or equality test.

In fact, the spec for [constructor patterns](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#constructor-patterns) doesn't directly address subtyping:

> The pattern matches all objects created from constructor invocations
>   c(v1,…,vn)

Of course, subclass construction necessarily invokes that constructor.

Back when [a case class could extend another case class](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/scala-Do-you-use-case-class-inheritance-td2001640.html), there might have been a higher expectation that pattern matching would distinguish subclasses, but that was before my time:

```
$ scala27
Welcome to Scala version 2.7.7.final (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_33).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> case class A(i: Int)                       
defined class A

scala> case class B(j: Int, s: String) extends A(j)
defined class B           

scala> (B(7,"hi"): Any) match { case A(7) => 1 case B(_,_) => 2 }
res1: Int = 1

scala> B(7,"hi").productArity                      
res2: Int = 2
```

I know from grammar school that some camels have one hump and others have two.