# Correct Spark dataframe type for arrays

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Regarding the following code:

```
val types = df.schema.fields.map(_.dataType)

types(i) match {
     case StringType => println("String")
     case ArrayType => println("Array")
     case _ => println("Miscellaneous")
}
```

ArrayType produces an error:

> Pattern type is incompatible with expected type, found:
>   ArrayType.type, required: DataType

On first glance it looks weird because both StringType (which doesn't produce an error) and ArrayType are located at the same location (org.apache.spark.sql.types).

But then after checking the hierarchy tree, I've figured out that the closest ancestor of both classes is AbsractDataType:

AbsractDataType -> DataType -> AtomicType -> StringType

vs

AbsractDataType -> ArrayType

`types` is an Array of DataType.

So I could probably just cast `types` to an Array of AbsractDataType, but I don't think it's the solution because if `types` is an Array of DataType then it means that also cells that contain arrays should be included there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all both `ArrayType` and `StringType` have basic class `DataType`. The hierarchy in both cases has as next:

```
StringType > AtomicType > DataType > AbsractDataType

ArrayType > DataType > AbsractDataType
```

I believe that in your example you confused the companion object of `ArrayType` which indeed inherits `AbsractDataType` object directly.

That means we can use pattern matching to derived types of `DataType` as you already did but the matching should occur based on the given constructor:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val df = Seq(
  ("1", Seq("A", "D", "B")),
  ("2", Seq("A", "D", "B")),
  ("3", Seq("B", "C", "G")),
  ("5", Seq("B", "D", "L"))
).toDF("ID","ar")

df.schema.fields.map{
    _.dataType match {
         case StringType => println("String")
         case ArrayType(_, _) => println("Array")
         case _ => println("Miscellaneous")
    }
}

// String
// Array
```

You can see that ArrayType expects two arguments since the definition is:

```scala
case class ArrayType(elementType: DataType, containsNull: Boolean) extends DataType
```

but `StringType` it doesn't:

```scala
class StringType private() extends AtomicType
```

Finally, if you only intended to get the string representation of each type you could also use the `typeName` property of `dataType`:

```scala
df.schema.fields.map{_.dataType.typeName}

// res24: Array[String] = Array(string, array)
```

### References

[Understanding Pattern Matching with Sub-classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28056521/understanding-pattern-matching-with-sub-classes)

https://users.scala-lang.org/t/correct-syntax-in-pattern-matching/2187/4

Answer (score 0):

Such construction can work:

```
types(i) match {
  case StringType => println("String")
  case _:ArrayType => println("Array")
  case _ => println("Miscellaneous")
}
```